# Reorganize directory structure MVC ExtJs 4 App

Tags: extjs-mvc

I have learned from the [sencha doc](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/application_architecture) how to create a simple MVC application, and now I wonder if it is possible to move from this structure :

```
-app
--Controller
---controller1.js
---controller2.js
   ...
--Model
---model1.js
---model2.js
   ...
--Store
---store1.js
---store2.js
   ...
--View
---view1.js
---view2.js
...
```

to this modular structure :

```
-app
--Module1
---controller.js
---model.js
---store.js
---view.js
--Module2
---controller.js
---model.js
---store.js
---view.js
```

I want also if you can advise me about the modular structure (good, bad, complex, remarks...), Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do whatever you want with different file and class names. Just remember to keep class name in sync with its position in the file hierarchy. For example if you have class

```
MyApp.controller.Controller1
```

located in the following file

```
- app\Controller\Controller1.js
```

If you move it to the

```
- app\module1\Controller.js
```

You would need to rename class name to

```
MyApp.module1.Controller
```

See for yourself whether having such class hierarchy would be appropriate for you. I would not do this. We keep all code according to ExtJs MVC directory structure (mostly). We have the following directories

```
- store
  -- base
- view
  -- base
- controller
- model
```

We usually put base classes underneath special base director to easily separate them from the rest of code.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful answer, just I want to add something about the modular folder structure, is that if your are in a team, and you want that each member take care of a specific task than I think that separating the application into modules is more convenient (I'm not sure!).

Comment: Not really. And it's very temporary. When all done and written your structure will remain with you forever :)

Comment: Agree with Adils comment. This approach is not modular... storing all your views, models, controllers, etc in different folders is splitting your modules up. It is extremely hard to work in projects setup like that. You lose sight of what files belong to your module (from a java perspective - inter package dependencies should be weak, not strong)